# NoMethodError at /charges undefined method `coupons' for nil:NilClass When creating coupon instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

please i am trying to create coupons for a particular ticket in my charges controller after a user has made payment but i keep getting this error; NoMethodError at /charges
undefined method `coupons' for nil:NilClass. Any help? Below is my code;

Ticket Model

```
class Ticket < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :event
 has_many :order_items, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :coupons, dependent: :destroy

 before_save :set_ticket_sku


 def ticket_sku
  self.sku = SecureRandom.hex
 end



  private
   def set_ticket_sku
      self[:sku] = ticket_sku
   end
  end
```

Coupon Model

```
class Coupon < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :ticket
 before_save :set_code

  def generate_code
    self.code = SecureRandom.hex
  end



 private
  def set_code
    self[:code] = generate_code
  end
end
```

Charges Controller

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController
skip_after_action :verify_authorized
before_action :authenticate_user!

def new
    
end


def create
    @order = current_order
    @order_items = @order.order_items.last 
    @amount = @order.subtotal_in_cents
    @ticket = Ticket.find_by(sku: params[:sku]) 
    @quantity = @order_items.quantity
    
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create({
        email: params['stripeEmail'],
        source: params['stripeToken']
    })

    charge = Stripe::Charge.create({
        customer: customer.id,
        amount: @amount,
        description: "Event Payment",
        currency: 'usd'
    })

    @quantity.times do 
        @ticket.coupons.create!
    end
    redirect_to root_path

rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    flash[:error] = e.message
    redirect_to new_charge_path
end
```

end

Comment: in your create action after `@ticket = Ticket.find_by (sku: params [: sku])` do `p @ticket`, chances are you are not getting an instance at that point.

Comment: yes the @ticket = Ticket.find_by (sku: params [: sku]) is not giving me an instance so please i do i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In charges controller Params[:sku] is nil

Comment: So how do i solve that problem? Because params[:sku] has value in it. @nishanth

Comment: Then with the value of Params[:sku] try to find Ticket.find_by(sku: params[:sku]) in console it will be empty